# Duplicate insert into table without date insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I'm having an insert problem with this script. Firstly, it is inserting each entry twice and it is inserting 00-00-00 for donation_date (which is DATE type on in my table). Below is my code.

First is the form:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td align=center>Donation Input Form</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <table>
  <?
  $querytype = "SELECT type FROM donation_type";
$typeresult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $querytype);

 $queryevent = "SELECT event FROM events";
$eventresult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryevent);

  $personid=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

  $order = "SELECT * FROM persons 
  where personid='$personid'";

  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$order);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="donor_update.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="personid" value="<? echo "$row[personid]"?>"> 
  <tr>ID:<? echo "$row[personid]"?><br /></tr>
  <tr>Donor Name:<? echo "$row[firstname] $row[surname]"?></tr>
    <tr>        
      <td>Donation Type:</td>
      <td>
    <select name='donation_type' class='required'>
    <option VALUE='donation_type'>Donation Type*</option>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($typeresult)) {
   echo ("<option VALUE=\"{$row['type']}\" " . ($result == $row['type'] ? " selected" : "") . ">{$row['type']}</option>");
      }
       ?>
      </td>
     </select>
      </tr>          
      <tr>        
      <td>Donation Event:</td>
      <td>
      <select name='event' class='required'>
     <option VALUE='event'>Donation Event*</option>
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eventresult)) {
     echo ("<option VALUE=\"{$row['event']}\" " . ($result == $row['event'] ? " selected" :   "") . ">{$row['event']}</option>");
      }
      ?>
     </select>
      </td>         
     </tr>

         <tr>
       <td>Date:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" name="donation_date" size="30" 
      value="">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Donation Amount ($):</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="amount" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[surname]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" 
      name="submit value" value="Submit">
      </td>
      </tr>
      </form>
     </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Which then goes to this script:

```
<?
require_once("models/config.php");

$personid =(trim($_POST['personid']));
$amount =(trim($_POST['amount']));
$donation_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['donation_date']));
$donation_type =(trim($_POST['donation_type']));
$event =(trim($_POST['event']));

 $order = "INSERT INTO donations (personid, amount, donation_date, donation_type, event)    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $order);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "siiss", $personid, $amount, $donation_date,     $donation_type, $event);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

 $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 if ($result === false) {
 echo "Error entering data! <BR>";
 echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
 } else {
 echo "<b>Donation entered</b><BR>";     
echo "Amount: $$amount <BR>";
echo "Donation Type: $donation_type <BR>";
echo "Event: $event <BR>";
echo "Date: $donation_date <BR>";
}
?>
```

What might be going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting 2 times is because of

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Remove the first one.

Now date going as 0000-00-00, you need to convert your input date to Y-m-d format.

You have

```
$donation_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['donation_date']));
```

Narrow down the debug by echoing $donation_date and see what you get.

In the bind param you have `i` for donation date it should be `s` since date is treated as string.

Comment: What do you mean? Change to `$donation_date = date('Y-m-d', ($_POST['donation_date']));` ?

Comment: I mean you have donation_date as text box and people can add date in any format so strtotime() may not be able to convert all format input date to Y-m-d, so was asking to echo that value and see what u get after the conversion.

Comment: In my form I have it as an HTML5 date select box. With my code as it stands, it is echoing the date as 2014-03-24 (my random selection).

Also, is "i" the right parameter switch for date?

Comment: ah found it you have "i" for donation date in bind param. Make it "s" since date is treated as string !!

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly it. For those learning, never use i in bind param for date.

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
<input type="date" name="donation_date" size="30" 
      value="">
```

Try to remove value="" and check it, it may creating issue.